# Find out HTTP method in PHP

Tags: php, http

How can I find out which method (usually GET or POST) is used for the current request?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

See [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). It will contain the request method upper-cased (i.e. 'GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT').

Answer (score 18):

While checking

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

seems the obvious choice, since some of the people are advocating safe superglobals alternatives ([Is using superglobals directly good or bad in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498207/is-using-superglobals-directly-good-or-bad-in-php) and similar questions), one may instead use automatic sanitizing

```
filter_input( \INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD', \FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS )
```

(you might of course use other filter, eg. `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` - see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) for a full list).

Obviously, in the regular (`GET`/`POST`) case there ain't anything to sanitize, but a good habit is still a good habit IMO.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: If you just want to know whether it is `GET` or `POST` or such, no filtering is required. However, you want to test the method and if not matched as expected, you can fallback to the "non-understood HTTP method" error (HTTP code 405). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#405

Comment: @AlexisWilke like I said, `in the regular (GET/POST) case there ain't anything to sanitize`; OTOH, if the result (the value of the variable) is, e.g. (and for whatever reason) further used as e.g. part of a output string or a autogenerated script body, and (again, for whatever reason) if the web server is bugged [(and there are bugs in web servers)](http://archive.apache.org/gnats/) and prone to injecting an invalid request method, this could *potentially* (albeit it's of course extremely unlikely) [result in arbitrary code execution or data generation](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: @MichaelJaros that's why I've written "possibly with (...) `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`" - but you're right, it's currently not clear enough, I rephrased it.