# How do I find out the version of HTTP in a request using PHP and Apache

Tags: php, apache, http-1.1, http-1.0

I need to determine whether an HTTP request was an HTTP/1.0 or an HTTP/1.1 request in my PHP script, which is running under Apache. Is there a way to query this information?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']` as at [`$_SERVER`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server):

> ***`'SERVER_PROTOCOL'`***
>   Name and revision of the information protocol via which the page was requested; i.e. `'HTTP/1.0'`;

See as well:

- [Find out HTTP method in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538065/find-out-http-method-in-php)