# Security concern when accessing php superglobal directly

Tags: php, security

I just upgraded my IDE (Netbean) to 1.7.4 beta, to test it out... and it seems that now it si giving me a warning whenever I access my superglobal variable. It says

> Do not access supergolobal $_POST Array Directly

I am currently just using this

```
 $taxAmount = intval(ceil($_POST['price']*($TAX-1)));
```

How much of a security concern is this really?

Is this the proper way to do it, and does it make a difference?

```
 $price = $_POST['price'];
 $taxAmount = intval(ceil($price*($TAX-1)));
```

Comment: Apparently netbeans wants you to use `filter_input()` instead. I'm not sure why it's such a bad thing, especially if you're sanitizing the data yourself. https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=234280

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can use you first method and not fill the memory with duplicate data. The only concern here is to validate it before using, and if you copy it to another variable, you need to do same on it also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any difference!

Especially if you do not want to use it in a sql_query.

The only thing that makes me thinking, is that **its not much common to write in superglobals directly**, so some poor programmers may leave it with *unvalidated* data.

One last thing, Be sure to check your "$_POST" existence with 'empty' or 'isset' functions.

example:

```
If(!empty($_POST['price']))
     $taxAmount = intval(ceil($_POST['price']*($TAX-1)));
else
     $taxAmount = -1; //Somethings wrong.
```

<sub>[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498207/is-using-superglobals-directly-good-or-bad-in-php)</sub>