# "Do not Access Superglobal $_SERVER Array Directly" on Netbeans 7.4 for PHP

Tags: php, netbeans

Yes, a similar question was posted and answered correctly.
[Warning "Do not Access Superglobal $_POST Array Directly" on Netbeans 7.4 for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767894/warning-do-not-access-superglobal-post-array-directly-on-netbeans-7-4-for-php)

That post was helpful.  but it did not resolve my problem.

I am not getting any OUTPUT in my browser.

I applied all of the options exchanging $_POST with $_SERVER.

My original code:

```
$user_ip = $_SERVER[ 'REMOTE ADDR'];
```

My code modified several ways as the other question/ answer suggests

```
user_ip = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REMOTE_ADDR');
user_ip = filter_input_array(INPUT_SERVER, 'REMOTE_ADDR');
```

STILL NO OUTOUT

Background.

I am appending code after code in my index.php as I go thru these tutorials.

I keep commenting out the previous code.

I missed a few comments and at that point I actually DID HAVE OUTPUT

```
::1
```

What I expected as output was

```
127,0,0,1
```

When I commented the all of the code from the previous tutorial
I no longer get any output.

I am going thru a tutorial which is very good but he is using xampp.
I am on a Mac and installed amp.
Don't know if that matters.

If you want to take a look, navigate to 
thenewboston.com
Tutorials
Php
Lesson 33
http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=33
First minute or so in.

Comment: `REMOTE ADDR` (with space) != `REMOTE_ADDR` (with underscore)... `::1` is the IPv6 loopback address, just as 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address for IPv4.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be sure to read the helpful formatting guide that appears when you click the orange question mark in the post editor.

Comment: @Marc b Sorry.  I did have an underscore in REMOTE_ADDR.

Comment: @marc b  admittedly, not new to programming but new to php.  Why am I not getting output ?   I am learning this using localhost.  Why would I even have REMOTE_ADDR in my code.

Comment: well, your PHP code is broken. You have no `$`, so you're trying to assign the filter results to undefined variables... `$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. There's no need to filter that one. It'll be an IP address that's determined by PHP. There's no way for a user to inject malicious data in there.

Comment: @marc b okay.  Too fast for me.  Once I get this stuff I am very intuitive but for now....  I do have an $ in my original line of code.  I did not filter to begin with but tried that suggestion from the question/response on this forum.

Comment: I am trying to figure out formatting for this forum <br> hope this works <br><br> no preview options and this makes it hard to comment upon the original post in a formatted fashion<br>code is  <br>$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];<br>
    echo  $string = 'your ip address is: '. $user_ip;<br>
    function echo_ip() {<br>
    $string = 'your ip address is: . '$user_ip;  <br>   <br><br>                                                        output <br>`code`your ip address is: ::1

Comment: If you want get variable from $_SERVER, how about use getenv()?

Answer (score 3):

When PHP is FastCGI based,
filter_input(INPUT_SERVER,…
and
filter_input_array(INPUT_SERVER…
don't return any results!

See the [PHP manual entry on filter_input, paying particular attention to the comment by **anthony dot parsons**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

Comment: Thanks.  This caused me some frustration, too.  One of MAMP's options on Mac is to run multiple versions of PHP, which requires running PHP as FastCGI... hence NO output for `filter_input_array(INPUT_SERVER)` other than PHP_SELF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER` directly and there is no need of use `filter_input`.The output  `::1` is just because you are running this code on Localhost. If you try your code on server(check you code on RemoteHost) then it will give your cLient's IP. Here is my code for fetch the Client's I.P. [See Snapshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrMxb.png)

```
   if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
    {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    }
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
    {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    }
    else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
```