# Netbeans: How to disable this single annoying warning?

Tags: php, netbeans, configuration, ide

The same problem which is occuring in this question is happening a lot to me: [Warning "Do not Access Superglobal $_POST Array Directly" on Netbeans 7.4 for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767894/warning-do-not-access-superglobal-post-array-directly-on-netbeans-7-4-for-ph)

However - of course I take care with $_POST and user input etc. but I do this with custom functions which NetBeans does not understand and therefore my IDE is full of warnings.

Another annoying example: "Too many nested blocks in function declaration". Of course you should avoid that, but I think this is not always possible.

How can I disable single warnings in the Netbeans IDE while still keeping all other warnings?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. Netbeans is not asking you to be careful.  Netbeans is asking you to use the [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function (PHP 5.2+) to totally replace $_XXYY.
2. You can switch off individual hint types from Tools > Options dialog.
   You can also change variables like how many nested blocks is too many:

[image: Editor > Hints > Language: PHP > Nested Blocks / Superglobals]