# How can I disable annoying warning/hint in NetBeans 8.1

Tags: java, netbeans, jersey

I am working with Java and Jersey in NetBeans and all my endpoints are flagged with the following hint:
"Convert Method To Asynchronous"

This hint really pollutes the right-hand gutter where I usually look for code changes/errors.

There is nothing in preferences -> editor -> hints that seems to affect this hint.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans: How to disable this single annoying warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797520/netbeans-how-to-disable-this-single-annoying-warning)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`@SupressWarning`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) annotation, or, by hovering the mouse-pointer over the warning, there are options to disable for instance (auto-generates `@SupressWarning`), for file, for package, for project or "forever" <sup><sub>(pah-dum-pshh =P)</sub></sup>.

However, most warnings are there for a reason, and although some can show up by "mistake" while your class isn't fully implemented yet, if your class is complete and a warning is still present, you're advised to correct it rather than suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked through the NetBeans source code ([here](http://hg.netbeans.org/main-silver/file/tip/websvc.rest/src/org/netbeans/modules/websvc/rest/editor/AsyncConverterTask.java)) and there's no way to disable/suppress that warning short of removing the REST module (/enterprise/modules/org-netbeans-modules-webscv-rest.jar).

Answer (score 0):

Did you use lombok? if yes you can remove the lombok library first then add it again