# Do not Access Superglobal $_SERVER Array Directly

Tags: php, netbeans

I know that instead of

```
$_POST['var_name']
```

I need to use

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'var_name')
```

but what about the first check, if the server has a POST request:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

does it have an equivalent? because Netbeans gives the warning

> Do not Access Superglobal $_SERVER Array Directly

Comment: _"instead of ...I need to use.."_ - who says so?

Comment: The server superglobal array is filled by the webserver. But the superglobal also contains unsafe http headers. That's probably why the warning gets shown. But the mentioned element is safe.

Comment: From the duplicate post, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24371536/283366) for specific details, including a link to [this Netbeans article](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/improve-your-code-with-new-hints)

Comment: @Jeff Netbeans says so (apparently).

Comment: @Jeff, haha yes, that's what Netbeans says. And about the duplicate post, I already saw it, but its `$_POST` and not `$_SERVER`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this :

```
$var_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $_POST["var_name"]);
```

we have many ways to get `REQUEST_METHOD` like :

```
getenv('REQUEST_METHOD');
```

If I'm wrong in the answer, it is because I did not find any code in the question :)

Comment: You could further distill your answer into: you could use `getenv('REQUEST_METHOD')` as an alternative to accessing the super global `$_SERVER`.  (Does netbeans still yield the same warning in that case?  What's the difference?  What are the ramifications of the first method?)

Comment: I did not find the code included and I answered what I know only :)