# Code issues not working, Not sure if my syntax is off or I am missing anything

Tags: php

Running into 5 errors that I can't seem to figure out since I am new to PhP so it's very confusing, this is for homework but I have done a good share I just need to figure out what the issues are will comment the code issues with the code

Issues are commented

I've tried to fix around syntax and ended up breaking things so I went back to it's original

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Shippee Credit Interest </title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2> Credit Interest Monthly Payments </h2>

        <form action="Shippeelab1.php" method="post">

            <!-- Input -->
            Credit:
            <input type="text" value="2157" name="credit">
            Interest Rating:
            <input type="text" value="26.22" name="interest">
            Monthly Payments:
            <input type="text" value="65" name="monthly">

            <!-- Button -->
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate!" name="btnCalc">

        </form>

        <?php

            if (isset ($_POST['btnCalc'])) // 1.Do not Access Superglobal $_POST Array Directly
            {

                $owe = $_POST['credit']; // 2. Do not Access Superglobal $_POST Array Directly
                $interest = $_POST['interest']; //Do not Access Superglobal $_POST Array Directly
                $payment = $_POST['monthly']; //Do not Access Superglobal $_POST Array Directly


                echo "<table align='left' border='3>";
                echo "<th> Months </th>";
                echo "<th> Interest </th>";
                echo "<th> Still Owed </th>";

                //Stored Balance
                $CC = $owe; 

            for ($array = 0; $owe > 0; $i++)
            {

                //Calulation for Interest 
                $paid = $owe * $interest / 100 / 12;

                //Interest Payments
                $bill = $owe + $interestPay; 

                //Balance Remainder
                $remainder = $owe - $payment + $interestPay;


                if($paid > $remainder)
                {
                    $remainder = "";
                }

                echo "<tr>"
                $rowMonth = $array + 1; //3. Syntax error  variable'$rowMonth'
                $rowInterest = '$' .number_format((float)$paid, 2);
                $rowRemainder '$'.number_format((float)$remainder, 2);//4. possible syntax error string '$'

                echo "<td> $rowMonth </td>";
                echo "<td> $rowInterest </td>";
                echo "<td> $rowRemainder </td>";

                echo "</tr>";

                $owe = $balance;
                }
            echo "</table>";

            $total = $CC + $bill;
            echo "<br>", "You paid over " .rowMonth, " months equals out to $".number_format((float)$total, 2);

            }

            else
            {

                echo "";

            }



        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's just not compiling and that is all I actually need it to do and I still think my syntax and issues are just things in the wrong place. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
My if statment will run but the error I get ends up being
[This is after changing the code but leaving is set as ($_POST["btnCalc"]))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N8Ci.png)

Comment: `//3.` is a missing `;` from the previous line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767894/warning-do-not-access-superglobal-post-array-directly-on-netbeans-7-4-for-ph

Comment: Thanks I fixed a bunch of the issues and Fox91 I tried the filter-input it works kinda but now I'm still getting errors my if big one is running the page I tried to change the Superglobal for my If statment for if (isset) but it broke the page

Comment: Added an image for you to review in the edit @fox91

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2 should be $_Post[""](Double quotes). 3 you're missing an ; after your echo. 4 $rowRemainder is not being set equal to anything.

Comment: Why do you need to use double quotes for 1&2?

Comment: Items within double quotes will be evaluated vs single will not be.

Comment: Correct - but how would that effect something like `$_POST['credit']`?

Comment: Those fixed a lot of the issues but I'm still having trouble with my if(isset)