# Is it normal to use parameters from .env file through $_ENV?

Tags: php, symfony4

Is it normal to use parameters in your own code from .env file through $_ENV variable? Of course in context of project using Symfony 4.

I have such code:

```
//WebhookUrlBuilder.php
class WebhookUrlBuilder
{

    private RouterInterface $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
            $this->router->getContext()->setHost($_ENV['HOST_URL'])->setScheme($_ENV['URL_SCHEME']);
        }
    }

    public function build(string $hash): string
    {
        return $this->router->generate(BotsController::WEBHOOK_URL_NAME, [
            'hash' => $hash
        ], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
    }
}
```

There is an opinion that using an $_ENV variable is bad taste, and I have to deliver these parameters through ParameterBag, like this:

```
#services.yml
parameters:
    host: '%env(HOST_URL)'
    scheme: '%env(URL_SCHEME)'
```

```
//WebhookUrlBuilder.php
class WebhookUrlBuilder
{

    private RouterInterface $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, ParameterBag $parameterBag)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
            $this->router
                 ->getContext()
                 ->setHost($parameterBag->get('host'))
                 ->setScheme($parameterBag->get('scheme'));
        }
    }

    public function build(string $hash): string
    {
        return $this->router->generate(BotsController::WEBHOOK_URL_NAME, [
            'hash' => $hash
        ], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
    }
}
```

But I consider that is useless extra action(copy values from .env variables to paramteres in services.yml) which doesn't bring any profit. What do u think?

Comment: Don't use any parameters from .env it's not secure to use any credentials from .env file

Comment: @PriyankMotivaras Why is that? What would you suggest to use instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is using superglobals directly good or bad in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498207/is-using-superglobals-directly-good-or-bad-in-php)

Comment: @PriyankMotivaras, why it's not secure?

Comment: @GutsOut accessible from root

Comment: @PriyankMotivaras then what is not accessible from root level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to decouple code from environmental variables, this make your code more portable and testable.
You should rewrite contstructor of `WebhookUrlBuilder` like this:

```php
//WebhookUrlBuilder.php
class WebhookUrlBuilder
{

    private RouterInterface $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, $host, $scheme)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
            $this->router
                 ->getContext()
                 ->setHost($host)
                 ->setScheme($scheme);
        }
    }

    public function build(string $hash): string
    {
        return $this->router->generate(BotsController::WEBHOOK_URL_NAME, [
            'hash' => $hash
        ], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
    }
}
```

and inject `$host` and `$scheme` via `services.yaml` like this:

```
#services.yml
parameters:
    host: '%env(HOST_URL)'
    scheme: '%env(URL_SCHEME)'
services:
    WebhookUrlBuilder:
        autowire: true
        arguments: ['%host%', '%scheme%']
```

Now, thanks to autowire, your builder is correctly instantiated and you can create new instances passing directly `$host` and `$scheme` per example in a phpunit test

Comment: Yeah yeah, absolutely agree with that approach, we also came to this conclusion. But the main question is there any point to packing .env params to parameterBag, and don't use them directly through $_ENV. For example, suppose a symfony container wouldn’t be able to inject these parameters into the constructor.

Comment: It depends on how much secure and trusted is your $_ENV. ParameterBag comes with useful filter methods (getAlnum(), getInt(), getBoolean(), etc) that come free with the framework, IMO is a must to filter not trusted env vars.