# Apache configuration for differentiating HEAD and POST methods

Tags: apache, .htaccess, post, methods, get

I have two files as follows:

- one.php
- two.php

Code for one.php

```
<?php
header( 'Location: two.php' ) ;
?>
```

Code for two.php

```
<?php
echo 'Hello Two' ;
?>
```

I wish to implement the following:

1. When a user access one.php using the http GET method, he/she
   should get a basic Auth prompt (401)
2. When a user access one.php using the http POST method, he / she should get the 405 - Method Not Allowed.
3. When a user access one.php using the http HEAD method, he / she should get the 302 Found.

I can implement the (1) and (2) with the help of .htaccess. However, since Apache consideres GET and HEAD as one, I am unable to implement (3). Is there any way I can implement the above scenario in Apache so that I can differentiate between GET and POST and configure .htaccess separately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out HTTP method in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538065/find-out-http-method-in-php)