# How can CURL be used to update sql table values in PHP?

Tags: php, api, curl

I am working on simple API and need to use PUT for updating the values in database. I am not able to sent data from the REST client (postman).
The following is the code.

```
switch ($method) {
case 'GET':
    $sql = "select * from trainsample";
    break;
case 'PUT':
    $sql = "UPDATE trainsample SET Name = $_PUT[Name] WHERE ID = $_PUT[ID] ";
    break;
case 'POST':
    $sql = "INSERT INTO trainsample VALUES ('$_POST[ID]','$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Place]','$_POST[Data]')";
    break;
case 'DELETE':
    $sql = "DELETE FROM trainsample WHERE ID = $_DELETE[ID]";
    break;
}
```

The GET and POST are working fine. But not able to perform PUT and DELETE. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's no such thing as `$_PUT` or `$_DELETE` in PHP. You'll need to parse `php://input` in your code, PHP doesn't do it automatically except for `POST` requests.

Comment: I have tried it also. But no luck

Comment: In a RESTful API, the parameters are in the URL, not in the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538065/find-out-http-method-in-php